# Fast and frequent file access while executing C++ code

Tags: c++, file, c++11, file-access

I am looking for suggestions on how best to implement my code for the following requirements. During execution of my c++ code, I frequently need to access data stored in a dictionary, which itself is stored in a text file. The dictionary contains 100 million entries, and at any point in time, my code would query data corresponding to some particular entry among those 100 million entries. There is no particular pattern in which those queries are made, and further during the lifetime of the program execution, not all entries in the dictionary are queried. Also, the dictionary will remain unchanged during the program's lifetime. The data corresponding to each entry is not all of the same length. The file size of my dictionary is ~24 GB, and I have only 16 GB of RAM memory. I need my application to be very fast, so I would like to know how best to implement such a system so that read access times can be minimized.

I am also the one who is creating the dictionary, so I do have the flexibility in breaking down my dictionary into several smaller volumes. While thinking about what I can do, I came up with the following, but not sure if either are good.

1. If I store the line offset for each entry in my dictionary from the beginning of the file, then to read the data for the corresponding entry, I can directly jump to the corresponding offset. Is there a way to do this using say ifstream without looping through all lines until the offset line? A quick search on the web seems to suggest this is not possible atleast with ifstream, are there are other ways this can be done?
2. The other extreme thought was to create a single file for each entry in the dictionary, so I would have 100 million files. This approach has the obvious drawback of overhead in opening and closing the file stream.

In general I am not convinced either of the approaches I have in mind are good, and so I would like some suggestions.

Comment: Store byte offsets rather than line numbers; then you can jump straight to the desired spot in the file. See [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [`tellg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg). I'd probably try to keep a hash table in RAM, from the hash of the key to the corresponding file offset.

Comment: You might consider using memory mapped files - boost has multiplatform implementation. As for performance - always profile your solution,

Comment: Implementing a trie might reduce the memory footprint. The reduction will depend on how many words start with the same prefixes. This might or might not be enough reduction for a complete in-memory solution.

Comment: It sounds like a job for a database. Any reason not to use one?

Comment: @marcinj thank you for the suggestion. I am wondering what is the tradeoff between memeory mapping and seekg calls as Igor suggests. A quick search seems to suggest to me that memory mapping internally uses seekg calls. However, is there are any convenience to using memory mapping over seekg? If you think this can warrant a separate question on stack exchange, I can create one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik-: Thanks for bringing seekg and tellg to my notice. A quick question, is seekg constant time access? I get the sense that this has to be the case, but am unable to confirm from what I read about it on the web.

Comment: @TedLyngmo- ideally i would like to obtain ram access speeds, my understanding is that it is going to significantly slower if done using a database. As you can see from my memory requirement figures, my application is s.t. my dictionary does not exceed my RAM memory by orders of magnitude, and that is why I am trying to first figure out if I can avoid using a database.

Comment: @batwing memory mapped files should move data from files to memory in system optimized way - index (offsets to each record) is still good idea.  Also abstract out the way you read records, so that you can switch between different solutions. And of course - profile each of those solution.

Comment: @batwing how many lookups are you going to do? What are the latency requirements? Can you explain why do you need such dictionary? It seems to be an algorithmic or design question, not c++ question.

Comment: @Roman - The code I am writing is a computational heavy code, I am using a dictionary to pre compute a few recurring optimization problems, so that it reduces the compute time. While perhaps I make < ~1 million queries during the lifetime of the program, I need to access the precomputed solutions rather quickly for justifying the use of my dictionary.

Comment: @batwing If you need to put the data on disk, it's going to get slower than if you can keep it all in memory, and you can't escape that fact by rolling your own version of a database (which is what an index + data file is). Chances are pretty high that the database uses whatever trickery is available (`mmap` etc) to make the access times and caching really good.

Comment: The upside of a memory mapped file is that A lump of the file will be loaded at each request, so neighbouring accesses are immediately resolved. If you just did the same random accesses on the file itself only the last accessed portion of the file is cached. Anything cleverer than that requires you to implement it. Note that most versions of glibc use memory mapping for FILE* opened for read by default anyway, so the only real benefit then is not having to copy the strings from the "secret" mmap area to the application buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you only need key value accesses, and if the data is larger than what can fit in memory, the answer is a NoSQL database. That mean a hash type index for the key and arbitrary values. If you have no other constraint like concurrent accesses from many clients or extended scalability, you can roll your own. The most important question for a custom NoSQL database is the expected number of keys that will give the size of the index file. You can find rather good hashing algorithms around, and will have to make a decision between a larger index file and a higher risk of collisions. Anyway, unless you want to use a tera bytes index files, your code must be prepared to possible collisions.

A detailed explaination with examples is far beyond what I can write in a SO answer, but it should give you a starting point.

The next optimization will be what should be cached in memory. It depends on the way you expect the queries. If it is unlikely to query more than one time the same key, you can probably just rely on the OS and filesystem cache, and a slight improvement would be memory mapped files, else caching (of index and/or values) makes sense. Here again you can choose and implement a caching algorithm.

Or if you think that it is too complex for little gain, you can search if one of the free NoSQL databases could meet your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Once you decide using on-disk data structure it becomes less a C++ question and more a system design question. You want to implement a disk-based dictionary. 
You should consider the following factors from now on are - what's your disk parameters? is it SSD? HDD? what's your average lookup rate per second? Are you fine having 20usec - 10ms latencies for your `Lookup()` method?

On-disk dictionaries require **random** disk seeks. Such seeks have a latency of dozens of microseconds for SSD and 3-10ms for HDD. Also, there is a limit on how many such seeks you can make a second. You can read [this article](http://www.thessdreview.com/featured/ssd-throughput-latency-iopsexplained/) for example. CPU stops being a bottleneck and IO becomes important.

If you want to pursue this direction - there are state of art C++ libraries that give you [on-disk key-value store](https://rocksdb.org/) (no need for out-of- process database) or you can do something simple yourself.

If your application is a batch process and not a server/UI program, i.e. you have another finite stream of items that you want to join with your dictionary then I recommend reading about external algorithms like [Hash Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join) or a MapReduce. In these cases, it's possible to organize your data in such way that instead of having 1 huge dictionary of 24GB you can have 10 dictionaries of size 2.4GB and sequentially load each one of them and join. But for that, I need to understand what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

To summarize, you need to design your system first before coding the solution. Using mmap or tries or other tricks mentioned in the comments are local optimizations (if at all), they are unlikely game-changers. I would not rush exploring them before doing back-on-the-envelope computations to understand the main direction.